# What is the difference between "mapped key sequences" and "key codes"? (timeoutlen v ttimeoutlen)

Tags: key-bindings

The [vim manual](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeoutlen%27) says we can use `timeoutlen` to specify the timeout length of *mapped key sequences* and can use `ttimeoutlen` to specify the timeout length of *key codes*:

> A useful setting would be
>
> ```
> :set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
> ```
>
> (time out on mapping after three seconds, time out on key codes after
>   a tenth of a second).

What are *key codes*? How are they different from *mapped key sequences*?

I know an example of a mapped key sequence is `jk` from the below mapping:

```
inoremap jk <esc>
```

In this example, when I'm in insert mode and type `j`, vim will wait `timeoutlen` milliseconds for me to press `k` before deciding what my intent is.

But what is a *key code* and how does `ttimeoutlen` affect it? Thanks you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In short:

- keycodes is a way to represent a key
- A mapped key sequence is a succession of keycodes triggering an action

---

Now I think that your question is more about the difference between `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen` instead of the difference between a mapped key sequence and a key code.

My answer is based on [this wikia article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim) that you really should read because it addresses some points that I didn't mention here to keep the answer as short and clear as possible.

---

First let's talk about key codes. The article defines two types of keycodes:

- **Terminal keycodes:**

They are how the terminal represents a key.

These codes that are sent by the terminal to Vim.

To get a list of these keycodes you should use your terminal documentation. You can also see them by typing the command `cat` in your terminal and typing the key you want to know the keycode of. For example on my terminal the key code for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> looks like:

> `^[[23~`

- **Vim keycodes:**

They are how vim represents a key.

Vim needs a consistent way to represent the keys because terminal's keycodes change from a terminal to another. A list of Vim keycodes is accessible at [`:h t_ku`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#t_ku). The Vim keycode for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> looks like:

> `<S-F1>`

Thus when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> on my keyboard, the drivers and OS will let the terminal know that I pressed these keys that it will interpret as `^[[23~`. The terminal will send that to Vim which will understand that it means `<S-F1>` and will trigger the action mapped to this key code.

We can set Vim keycodes, so if your terminal sends a keycode that Vim doesn't understand like `<S-F1>` for example you could use the following command. This will tell Vim when you receive the keycode `^[[24~`, translate it as `<S-F1>`:

```
set <S-F1>=^[[24~
```

**So what is a mapped key sequence?**

A mapped key sequence will be a lhs of a mapping and can be Vim key codes or Terminal key codes. For example:

```
:nmap ^[[24~ :bn<CR>
:nmap <S-F1> :bn<CR>
```

The first mapping will map the terminal keycode while the second maps the Vim keycode.

**Now for the difference between `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`?**

- `ttimeoutlen` is the time Vim will wait for the different parts of a terminal key code (in our previous example that would be `^[` then `[` then `2`, etc...

As these keycodes are sent by the terminal there should not be a delay between these inputs (since they are sent 'all at once' by the terminal). This is why the doc recommends a really small value for this setting.

- `timeoutlen` is the time Vim will wait for the successive Vim keycodes which are entered manually by a user and thus is longer to input than a terminal keycode.

To use an example let's say that:

- You mapped `^[[1;6B` to an action
- `^[1;6B` is your terminal's keycode for <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>
- `^[` is your terminal's keycode for <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

The behavior that you should expect:

- If you set a large `ttimeoutlen`, each time you type on <kbd>Escape</kbd>, Vim will wait to see if you meant `^[` (i.e. <kbd>Escape</kbd>) or `^[1;6B` (i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>)
- If you set a small `ttimeoutlen`, you will not have a delay when you type <kbd>Escape</kbd> because Vim will know that it is a complete keycode.

And `timeoutlen` will act on a 'higher level', if you have the following mappings:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
inoremap jk <Esc>:nohl<CR>
```

When you type <kbd>j</kbd> vim will wait `timeoutlen` not because the beginning of the terminal keycode for <kbd>j</kbd> is not complete but because it is waiting for the next Vim keycode.

---

I hope my explanation makes sense, note that some of the mappings I used don't make sense in a functional point of view but are here for the convenience the explanation.